# Prevent Obj-C framework class naming conflict with NSUnit in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, foundation

Given the following Objective-C class `Unit` which exists in a embedded framework in my project:

```
@interface Unit : NSObject

// ...

@end
```

And `Product`:

```
@interface Product : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Unit *> *units;

//...

@end
```

The following code in my main project (which is a Swift 4 project):

```
extension Product {

    var children: [NSObject] {
        var children: [NSObject] = []

        if let units = self.units {
            for unit in units {
                children.append(unit)
            }
        }

        return children
    }

}
```

Produces the following crash and error at runtime (Occurs on the `for` loop line):

```
Could not cast value of type 'Unit_Unit_' (0x618000452930) to 'NSUnit'
(0x7fff90c579b8).
```

Is there a way to force the cast of the framework `Unit` class in such a way as to not conflict with the `NSUnit` class?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
if let units = self.units as? [MyFramework.Unit] {
    for unit in units { // <-- Crash occurs on this line
        children.append(unit)
    }
}
```

Am I simply out of luck and can't use Swift with this Objective-C framework due to two objects being named `Unit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround by doing the following forced casting:

```
if let units = self.units {
    let unitsArray: [NSObject] = (units as NSSet).allObjects as! [NSObject]
    for unit in unitsArray {
        children.append(unit)
    }
}
```

Perhaps this will help someone else out!